# Domain of $\frac{ln(y)}{\sqrt{x-y}}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

i wanted to know why $x>y \land y>0 \ne x>y \lor y<0$

the left answer is the teacher, the right one is me

thanks for the answer

Comment: i found the answer while posting, it's the $ln(y)$ so $y > 0$ i dont know how to delete post, i'll do later.

Comment: Keep your question up: you are allowed to answer your own question. You might be able to provide a better explanation than the answer below because you have the full context, whereas the other user does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is given by the conditions: $y>0$ because of the $\log y$, $x-y>0$ because of the square root and the denominator different from $0$; so it must be $x>y>0$.
Your mistakes are:

1. you use $\lor$, that means "or" so it gives the meaning that one condition, other condition or both conditions are allowed, while you need that the conditions must be true all together, so you have to use $\land$ that means "and";
2. you say $y<0$ instead of $y>0$.